# video preview distortion + air for android

Tags: android, flash, video-streaming, live-streaming, distortion

I am trying to make a live streaming android application using flash (air for android). 
My application can be used to stream video from the device to the server.

The code that i used for this is as follows:

```
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.net.NetStream;

var cam:Camera = new Camera();
cam = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(videoView.width, videoView.height, 15, true);
videoView.attachCamera(cam);

var netCon:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
netCon.client = this;
netCon.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
netCon.connect("rtmp://url.com/live");

var netStream:NetStream;

function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {

        trace("pulishing");
        netStream = new NetStream(netCon);
        netStream.attachCamera(cam);
        netStream.publish("testlive");

    }
}
```

The above program stream the video from device cam to the server successfully in most of the device and we can see the video being taken in the device. But in certain devices, the video gets distorted.

I have attached the screen of the distorted video. Can any one help me out to trace this issue? I have searched a lot about this, but couldn't find any good answers.

The device in which i face such an issue is a custom made android device which runs on 4.0.4

The image shown here is what i obtain on my device screen. However, when i stream the captured video on JWplayer, it shows the video without any distortion.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP1wa.png
```